# jQuery - Post with click and Enter key

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a basic form which I use to post comments. Looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chat-input" placeholder="Message...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="chat-enter" class="btn btn-default go-chat" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

And I process the data using jquery and ajax. I would like to be able to post the comment by clicking the `Go!` button as well as hitting the `Enter` key. For some reason the code below is not working. It only works if the button is clicked.

```
//Save comments
function saveComment(id, comment) {
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/chat.php",
        data: { item_id: id, comment: comment },
            success:function(result)
            {
             alert("done");
            }

    });
}

$(".go-chat").click(function() {
    var comment = $("#chat-input").val();
    var id = getParameterByName('id');

    saveComment(id, comment);

});

$('body').on('keypress','#chat-enter', function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var comment = $("#chat-input").val();
        var id = getParameterByName('id');
        saveComment(id, comment);
    }
});
```

** Edit **

```
$("#comment-form").submit(function(e) {
    var comment = $("#chat-input").val();
    var id = getParameterByName('id');

    saveComment(id, comment);

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: go with `keyup`, instead of `keypress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use submit button and form submit event handler like(It will handle the enter key press within the form)

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="chat-input" placeholder="Message..."/>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button id="chat-enter" class="btn btn-default go-chat" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

then

```
//Save comments
function saveComment(id, comment) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/chat.php",
        data: {
            item_id: id,
            comment: comment
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert("done");
        }

    });
}

$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var comment = $("#chat-input").val();
    var id = getParameterByName('id');

    saveComment(id, comment);
    //prevent default form submit
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Comment: Enter key still refreshes the page. I used your suggestion, with one small modification. I added an `id` to the form. `#comment-form`, and instead of `$("form")` I used `$("#comment-form")`. Clicking the submit still works.

Comment: I see ... but I can't use `"form"`. I have multiple forms on the page. So I have to target that specific form. Let me work on it and I'll see what I come up with. Thank you!

Comment: So weird ... it works. So why wouldn't it work for me?

Comment: @ciprian can you update the fiddle with your html and script... any error in your browser console

Comment: Scratch that. It worked :D I think the js is cached or something ... cause it took a few refreshes to get it working.

Comment: This is so funny. Now clicking the submit button doesn't work. And no errors in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78734/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-ciprian).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by triggering *click* event on `Go!` button when **enter** gets pressed.

```
$('body').onkeypress( function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('#chat-enter').click();
 }
}
```

In this way everything will be handled by your *click event handler* associated with `Go!` button.

You may use *onkeyup* instead of *onkeypress*. And you can associate it with the input field instead of *body* tag.